# Ncurses gives different colors on different platforms

Tags: c, ncurses

Ncurses gives me blue color in MacOs for RBG tuple `init_color(COLOR_NAVY_BLUE, 0, 0, 139);`which is desired. But when running the same program on linux color is yellow. Why colors are different and how can I make it unified across platforms?
Both MacOs and linux terminals: xterm-256color.

Comment: "linux terminal" is vague: what you're talking about wouldn't work for Linux console.  Other terminal emulators in Linux would have different behavior.

Comment: The preferences for the Terminal app on macOS, or xterm on Linux or most emulators let you custom configure the color palette for the standard set of basic colors like RGB(0xf, 0, 0), RGB(0,0x8, 0), RGB(0, 0, 0xf), RGB(0, 0xf, 0xf) ... unused 12 bit color... example :-). In fact when I went with a terminal color with a black background the other day, dmesg output on Linux was unreadable until I edited the palette. But ultimately it is the end user that will decide the colors and the conformity among their terminal emulator(s) of choice.

Comment: not all terminals allow colors to be redefined. additionally, not all terminals support more than 3 or 4 bit color (8 and 16 colors). Because of this, you cannot expect colors to be the same on every platform.